# Intermediate Analysis Book Suggestions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

the title basically says it all.  I am looking for real/functional analysis books that would be considered "intermediate level" by that I mean books harder than baby rudin, and easier than big rudin. In general, I'm looking for something with good coverage of non measure theory material, although its understandable if such books contain measure theory. I guess I'm looking for something similar to royden.  Mainly, I want to be able to find some difficult problems related to contraction mapping, normed spaces, stone-weierstrass, and arzela-ascoli. I realize that there may be some relevant questions already asked so if someone could point me to the right threads, that would be helpful too.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One nicely written book is [Simmons](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1575242389).

Comment: Absolutely - very well written and gives a thorough yet gentle introduction to some nice topics.